# Listing quoted sentences: separate them with a semicolon, comma, period (or none)?

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons, quotation-marks, periods

I am completing a manuscript for my recent book. I would love to know whether I need to put a comma, semicolon, or other form of punctuation (or none) in-between these quoted sentences.

The examples are below. Which one of these sentences is correctly punctuated?

- For example, you could choose to say, "Thank you, you are very kind. I
  will let you know"; "I appreciate your offer, but I've made a decision
  already"; "Thanks! I'll think about your offer for a few days and I'll
  get back to you."
- For example, you could choose to say, "Thank you, you are very kind. I
  will let you know," "I appreciate your offer, but I've made a decision
  already," "Thanks! I'll think about your offer for a few days and I'll
  get back to you."
- For example, you could choose to say, "Thank you, you are very kind. I
  will let you know." "I appreciate your offer, but I've made a decision
  already." "Thanks! I'll think about your offer for a few days and I'll
  get back to you."

Which of these are correct? **Notice how the first paragraph has a semicolon, the second has a comma, and the third has a period within the quoted text.**

I'd love to hear your expert knowledge!

Comment: This is always a dilemma.  I would change the comma after "say" to a colon and then use the 3rd option.  (But for sentences without commas I might be inclined to option 2.)  (But note that I'm an engineer, not an editor.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you're going to find an authoritative answer for this question. And I'd assume that it boils down to a matter of style (preference) rather than constraints. You could use bullet points, but perhaps you'd prefer a more flowing style. Personally. I'd choose your first version, with an 'or' after the second semicolon. I prefer the 'outside-the-quote' sectioning punctuation, though I'd not worry about using **!";** or **?";** (or even **.";**) if necessary. I doubt you'll find an endorsement closer than the following (listed sentences but not quoted sentences) from [uno.edu/lrc/writingcenter](http://www.uno.edu/lrc/writingcenter/documents/SEMICOLONS-COLONS.pdf) which recommends:

> Semicolons are generally used for lists of sentences. Although some
>   grammar handbooks agree that short sentences that all follow the same
>   grammatical pattern
>
> (I came, I saw, I conquered)
>
> can be separated by
>   commas, it is safer to use semicolons:
>
> Francis Wayland Thurston was appalled at the statue he found: it was a
>   dragon; it was an octopus; it was a monster.